# Android WebView with Chrome 50 blocking Javascript until touching the page

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webview

I have an app with 4 tabs at the bottom, each hosting a stack of WebViews showing webpages rendered by Javascript (including calling Javascript bridge functions to change native title bar).

On most devices it's OK to fast switch tabs. But on devices with Chrome 50 as the kernel of the WebView, Javascript scripts are deferred when switching tabs fast, and won't run until I touch the screen.

Any way to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: How did you get android webview with chrome 50?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
requestIdleCallback(long_running_function);
```

to wrap the long-running function solved the problem!